# Apache POI cannot create excel XSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I cannot create an instance of XSSFWorkbook. My code fails on the line:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Here the exception trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.getMethod(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:73)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.<clinit>(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.getNoType(XmlBeans.java:856)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:881)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook$Factory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:407)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:219)
    at excel.readExcelFile(excel.java:24)
    at client.readInputFile(client.java:66)
    at client.main(client.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.<clinit>(Path.java:70)
    ... 16 more
```

Here jars that I've added to project:

- poi-3.12-20150511
- poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511
- xmlbeans-2.6.0
- commons-codec-1.9
- commons-logging-1.1.3
- log4j-1.2.17

After reading some info I've also tried to add:

- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- poi-excelant-3.12-20150511.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar

with no effect. What could be the reason?

**Update:**
Problem was that I added jars in user lib and add it to project build path. But once I add them directly to build pass - error goes away

Comment: can you check this java file and put what there is.. at excel.readExcelFile(***VulnExcel.java:24***)

Comment: According to the source code of POI, XMLBeans looks for META-INF/services/org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.PathDelegate.SelectPathInterface in its own JAR: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlbeans/trunk/src/store/org/apache/xmlbeans/impl/store/Path.java Ensure that XMLBeans 2.5 isn't included in another JAR. Use only XMLBeans 2.6.0.

Comment: try using new XSSFWorkbook(fileName);

Comment: @ManojP it gives the same result

Comment: @sgpalit there is the line 'XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()'

Comment: It looks like the problem was with JRE System Library. I switched from JRE SE 1.8 to JDK1.8.0_25 and this problem dissapeared.